# Assign value from then function to a variable promise

Tags: angularjs, deferred

I am trying to get hands in promises. SO i wrote a sample code like below

```
<!doctype html>
<html  ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    <script src="../angularjs.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="CartController">
    </div>

  <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('CartController',  function($scope, $q,$http){   

    $scope.newFun = function()
    {
      var defered = $q.defer();
      $http.get('data.json').success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        defered.resolve(data);
      })
      .error(function(data, status) {
        console.error('Repos error', status, data);
      });
      return defered.promise;
     }

     var newdata = $scope.newFun().then(
      function(data1) 
      {
        //console.log(data1);
        return data1;
      });

      console.log(newdata);
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here i am trying to return the data got from the then function and assign it to a variable. But i am getting a $$ state object, which has a value key which holds the data. Is directly assigning the value is possible or inside the then function i need to use scope object and then access the data??

Comment: `newdata` is promise object, you need to assign scope variables within one of those promise callbacks. Also no need to use `$q` in this instance since `$http` returns a promise itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many problems with your code.. To start with: you [can't return from asynchronous operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), you need to use callbacks for this. In your case since you are using promises use `then` API of it. Inside of its callback you would assign your data to variable. Angular will do the rest synchronizing scope bindings (by running new digest).

Next problem: don't use `$q.defer()`, you simply don't need it. This is the most popular [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns).

One more thing: don't make any http requests in controller, this is not the right place for it. Instead move this logic to reusable service.

All together it will look something like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('CartController', function ($scope, data) {
    data.get().then(function (data) {
        var newdata = data;
    });
});

app.factory('data', function($http) {
    return {
        get: function() {
            return $http.get('data.json').then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            }, function (err) {
                throw {
                    message: 'Repos error',
                    status: err.status, 
                    data: err.data
                };
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: I am very much confused when to use .then and .success. If possible can you brief me

Comment: Success is sort of shorthand for `then(function(response) { return response.data })`. I would recommend always use `then`.

Comment: When is the ideal situation when i should use $q.defer ?

Comment: You should use defer in case of non-promise functions when you need to return a promise. Things like $http, $timeout already return promises, so you don't need redundant $q.defer. You would use it for example in case of custom function that doesn't return promise. For example http://jsfiddle.net/97LvLo6e/