# Assign value from localforage.getItem to global variable - ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, localforage

I had problems with my localforage, where localforage can't set a global variable in the success callback but when i `console.log` display showing values.

**Localforage data:**

```
Key: login
Value: [{"token": "bla bla bla", "member_id":1}]
```

**Code**

```
public login_data: any;
getMemberData() {
  localforage.getItem("login").then(function(value){
    this.login_data = value[0];
  });
  console.log(this.login_data);
}
```

**Output**

```
undefined
```

All I want is to make it into a global variable. And I can use it easily, such as:

```
this.login_data.member_id
or
this.login_data.token
```

Some ways I have tried not correspond to my expectations. **i have tried:**

[Assign value from successful promise resolve to external variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264153/assign-value-from-successful-promise-resolve-to-external-variable)

[how to assign the returned value of a promise to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612877/how-to-assign-the-returned-value-of-a-promise-to-a-variable)

[setting a variable to get return from call back function using promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22536385/setting-a-variable-to-get-return-from-call-back-function-using-promise)

[Assign value from then function to a variable promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32924048/assign-value-from-then-function-to-a-variable-promise)

**[Note]** I use Ionic 2, AngularJS 2, LocalForage

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The promise is evaluated and then sets `this.login_data = value[0];` .If you change your console output inside the promise see if it shows the output properly.

```
localforage.getItem("login").then(function(value){
this.login_data = value[0];
console.log(this.login_data);
 });
```

UPDATE -- please share output

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.login_data= "My login details";
  console.log('Init to empty : ' );
  console.log(this.login_data);
  console.log('--------');
  this.getMemberData();       
 }


getMemberData() {
 localforage.getItem("login").then(function(value){
 console.log(value[0]);
 console.log('My Init login data still is -');
 console.log(this.login_data);
 console.log('--------');
 this.login_data = value[0];
 console.log('After fetch -');
 console.log(this.login_data);
 console.log('--------');
 });  
}
```

Comment: it displays an error: `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'login_data' of null`

Comment: So you have your value correctly fetched, now its setting it against the login_data object. Correct ? Try setting`this.login_data = 'Login data'` manually, and display the output. See if its even accepting anything. Then check `value` that you fetch. Are you able to share that result ?

Comment: I think `value` or `value[0]` is null,may be because it doesn't exist or not reachable from the module.So i would step back to see how to fetch the item..and may be even check storage via browser devtools to see if the item exists. Call  `getMemberData()` inside `ngOnInit()`..

Comment: when I 'console.log (value [0])' it displays the correct result, I have tried to set the manual but did not change anything(same error), any idea?

Comment: Fair enough, atleaset  we know that data is fetched correctly. Did you try this in `ngOnInit` ? and set `this.login_data = {}` in `ngOnInit`; its only declared as type `any` and not initialized. Hope you are following.. then call `getMemberdata()` after.

Comment: no changes, i add it before the `constructor` like this:

Comment: `ngOnInit() {
    this.login_data = {};
  }`

Comment: Updated answer.